# Can't connect to socket using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-studio, telnet

I have a problem connecting to telnet using Android Studio. Connecting through a terminal works just fine, but when I try to connect to Android Studio it doesn't connect. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I can tell it's not connected because when I look at my telnet connection, a new message should come up, but the telnet does not change at all. I can provide extra information, if needed.

My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String LOGTAG = "MainPAge";

    private ServerConnect mSC;

    Thread serverThread = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.i(LOGTAG, "onCreate entered");

        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerConnect(this));
        this.serverThread.start();

        // Connect to server and continue from here TODO
        //// Your code should go here
        final Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendCmd);



;
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });


        //Makes the receiving text area scrollable
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtServerResponse);
        tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        //This is an example of how to set events to button clicks
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnKill);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //OnClick actions here
                System.exit(0);

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

ServerConnect.java:

```
public class ServerConnect extends Thread{

    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

    private Socket socket;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 9999;         //This is the port that we are connecting to
                                                        //Remember the channel simulator is 9998

    private static final String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.2";  //This address is magically mapped to the host's loopback.
    private static final String LOGTAG = "SocketTester";

    boolean terminated = false;

    private PrintWriter out = null;
    private BufferedReader in = null;

    Activity parentref;

    /**
     *
     * @param parentRef Expects a reference to the calling activity, e.g. new ServerConnect(this);
     */
    public ServerConnect(Activity parentRef)
    {
        parentref=parentRef;
    }

    /**
     * Sends commands to the server. Called from UI thread via a button press
     * @param cmd
     */
    public void send(String cmd)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.i(LOGTAG,"Sending command: "+cmd);
            out.println(cmd);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(LOGTAG,"Failed to send command : "+e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main thread loop that grabs incoming messages
     */
    public void run()
    {
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Running socket thread");


        try
        {
            InetAddress svrAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            socket = new Socket(svrAddr, SERVERPORT);

            //Setup i/o streams
            out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()),true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //Keep listening for messages from server
            while(!terminated)
            {

                final String message = in.readLine();
                if(message != null && message != "")
                {
                    Log.i(LOGTAG,"MSG recv : "+message);

                    //Update GUI with any server responses
                    final TextView txtv = (TextView) parentref.findViewById(R.id.txtServerResponse);
                    parentref.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {



                            /**
                             *
                             *
                             * This is where the the UI gets updated by the socket
                             *
                             *
                             */
                            Log.i(LOGTAG, "TEST");


                            txtv.setText(message+"\n"+txtv.getText());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        }
        catch (UnknownHostException uhe)
        {
            Log.e(LOGTAG,"Unknownhost\n"+uhe.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Socket failed\n"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        disconnect();
        Log.i(LOGTAG,"Thread now closing");
    }

    /**
     * Disconnect from the server as well as closing i/o streams
     */
    public void disconnect()
    {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Disconnecting from server");
        try
        {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {/*do nothing*/}

        try
        {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {/*do nothing*/}


    }

}
```

And my stacktrace:

```
04-21 03:26:22.944 25927-25927/? E/Zygote: v2
04-21 03:26:22.944 25927-25927/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10004
04-21 03:26:22.944 25927-25927/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
04-21 03:26:22.944 25927-25927/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-G920F_5.1.1 ver=38
04-21 03:26:22.944 25927-25927/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0008
04-21 03:26:22.944 25927-25927/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-21 03:26:22.944 25927-25927/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 
04-21 03:26:22.944 25927-25927/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-21 03:26:22.984 25927-25927/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
04-21 03:26:22.984 25927-25927/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
04-21 03:26:23.314 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 rsrc of package uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4
04-21 03:26:23.314 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
04-21 03:26:23.314 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
04-21 03:26:23.324 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
04-21 03:26:23.324 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4-2/lib/arm64
04-21 03:26:23.334 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
04-21 03:26:23.334 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4
04-21 03:26:23.334 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 I/InjectionManager: Constructor uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4, Feature store :{}
04-21 03:26:23.334 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
04-21 03:26:23.334 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 rsrc of package uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4
04-21 03:26:23.334 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4-2/base.apk / 1.0 running in uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 rsrc of package uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4
04-21 03:26:23.424 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 I/MainPAge: onCreate entered
04-21 03:26:23.424 25927-25953/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 I/SocketTester: Running socket thread
04-21 03:26:23.424 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
04-21 03:26:23.424 25927-25953/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 I/SocketTester: LOL
04-21 03:26:23.434 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4.MainActivity isFragment :false
04-21 03:26:23.434 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
04-21 03:26:23.434 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{32ba211 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
04-21 03:26:23.444 25927-25954/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-21 03:26:23.534 25927-25954/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
04-21 03:26:23.554 25927-25954/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f7a7fa178
04-21 03:26:23.554 25927-25954/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-21 03:26:23.564 25927-25954/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
04-21 03:26:23.584 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{5c6e414 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7720f66 {uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4.MainActivity}} show : true
04-21 03:26:23.594 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4.MainActivity
04-21 03:26:23.594 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4.MainActivity
04-21 03:26:23.604 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
04-21 03:26:23.604 25927-25954/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4
04-21 03:26:23.754 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=1
04-21 03:26:23.764 25927-25927/uk.ac.man.cs.COMP28512.lab4 I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@7720f66 time:49211824
```

Any help is appreciated!